# Email images not displaying ONLY in Outlook Desktop

Tags: email, email-template, document

EDIT: I posted a similar question (attacking this problem from the Outlook end) over at Super User: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1240628/outlook-desktop-does-not-download-images-from-salesforce)

I have an email template that uses a letterhead with an image (document) at the top. I have set the accessibility settings on the Document folder to public read-only, and I have checked that the image is publicly available. If I send the email out, everything works well UNLESS I open the email on Microsoft Outlook desktop. When I open the email in Outlook Desktop, I am prompted to download images (like I am for all emails.) When I click "Download Images", instead of receiving my expected image I receive a small icon with a red x. I don't seem to have this problem with any other images, so I think it is a Salesforce issue, not an Outlook one, but if there isn't a satisfactory SF answer I'll post over on Super User.

To summarize the problem:

- Send email, open in Outlook Desktop: **Image does not display**
- Send email, open in Gmail in browser: **Image works**
- Send email, open in Outlook Mobile: **Image works**

Comment: Probably, you'll have to check with SF support only.